# Basic node/mongo/mongoose connection not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm new to MEAN stack development. I've created a database in MongoDB called 'framework' and a collection called 'users' with some json in. I can see that's all there and happy using mongo commands through Mac terminal.

Now I'm writing some Mongoose in my application and to test everything is working, I just want to get a list of the collection names. I tried this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/framework");

mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function (err, names) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(names);
});
```

But when I run that file through the command line, it doesn't log anything at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think that you forget the port at localhost. by default mongo running at 27017.

Comment: Port is not required if it's 27017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it as a `callback` function after the `connection` is **successfully established**. Without it being inside a callback method, it may get executed before the connection to the database is successfully established due to its `asynchronous` nature.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/framework");

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function (err, names) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(names);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames is deprecated. Use this code to get the list of all collections

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/framework");
mongoose.connection.on('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to mongodb server.');
  mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
    console.log(names);
   });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not pretty sure of what should be the URL string for your mongoose.connect method. No worries, go to your command prompt, type **mongo**.

This starts the application where you can see the connection details like

[image]

Then use the same URL with your db-name appended like

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db-name").then(
    ()=> console.log('connected to db')
).catch(
    (err)=> console.error(err)
);
```

Hope this helps !!